# copy file from source to dest even if file exist in dest with ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, copy

as I understand, the following line should copy files even if the file exist already within the destination folder:

```
FileUtils.cp_r(source, 'destination')
```

I get the EACCES error:

```
fileutils.rb:1402:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen ...
```

Which means I can not overwrite the already existing file.

How to overwrite  files with same name using FileUtils.cp_r?

Comment: `FileUtils.chmod(0777, source)` and then `FileUtils.cp_r source, 'destination', remove_destination: true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

send in `remove_destination: true` in your options block

Comment: And how do we do that?